# Sonata admin list editable conflict with edit / show

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I add editable field

```
 $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->addIdentifier('name',null,[
                'editable' => true,
            ])
```

But it's not editable, name is link to edit.

How disable creating link without disable edit route ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addIdentifer` method is to create a link.

If you don't want a link, you need to use `add` method

```
$listMapper
 ->addIdentifier('id')
 ->add('name',null,[ 'editable' => true, ])
```